# view can't find objects

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Hi I have a article model and I want to show my 5 newest articles. when I go to the url I give not fount error but i have 5 articles i don't know why doesn't show me.

```
class Article(models.Model):
    page_title = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    article_title = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=300, unique=True, allow_unicode=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='articles_pic/%Y/%m/%d/')
    content = RichTextUploadingField()
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    show = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.article_title
```

.

```
class NewestArticles(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = Article.objects.filter(show=True).order_by('-created')[:5]
    serializer_class = ArticleSerializer
    permission_classes = (AllowAny,)
```

.

```
path('new_articles/', views.NewestArticles.as_view(), name='new_articles')
```

[image]

Comment: Can you post the full traceback? Normally it will show the patterns it tried.

Comment: you mean share the error screen shot ? i don't understand

Comment: just copy the full error message when the `DEBUG = True` setting is set to `True`.

Comment: I edited my question

Comment: Can you add the full `urls.py` file to the question? You seem to have a detail view serving that path, maybe you have some conflicting url patterns

Comment: It looks like you have a `DetailAPIView` *before* this one, and it sees `new_articles` as the slug/... for that article.

Comment: yes exactly. i think if i put this url  above the detail view it would be ok